# python ThreadPoolExecutor, pass in a value from a list for each thread

Tags: python, multithreading, list, threadpoolexecutor

this is an example of the code i have now:

```
def target_func(i):
    global result
    result += i

list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4...1000]
thread_count = 100
result = 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_count) as executor:
            executor.map(target_func, list_a)
            time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

my goal is to start a thread for each element in list_a while not exceeding the maximum number of running threads which is specified in `thread_count` variable, but my code runs the elements multiple times, im new to threading in python so i don't know whats wrong here or if im using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` right.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all what you need to do is litle change.
change this line

```
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_count)
```

to this one

```
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=thread_count)
```

Comment: This is not True -- `max_workers` is also the first positional argument.

Comment: yes right it first but if you do not define it using max_workers= number it will be None because is defined *arg

Comment: I've updated you answer because some people are difficult to convince. You should delete your answer before it gets downvoted. `max_workers` is only `None` if the argument is not provided at all. It can be provided as a keyword or positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "my code runs the elements multiple times?"

First, the `map` function returns an iterator. To be sure that all tasks submitted have been completed you can either iterate the iterator:

```py
list(executor.map(target_func, list_a))
```

Or you can wait until `shutdown(wait=True)` has been called on the pool, which implicitly happens following the end of the `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_count) as executor:` block.

Second, the operation `result += i` may not be atomic. It is possible that two threads could be reading the same value and thus incrementing `result` to the same updated value and you will end up with a final value for `result` that is not the sum of all the elements of `list_a`. You should ensure that only one thread at a time can be executing this statement by using a `Lock`.

Finally, this is not a great use case for multithreading since your worker function `target_func` has no I/O and will not regularly release the Lobal Interpreter Lock (GIL). It's also not a great use case for multiprocessing since the function is too trivial.

```py
import concurrent.futures
from threading import Lock

def target_func(i):
    global result
    with lock:
        result += i

list_a = [i for i in range(1, 1001)]
thread_count = 100
result = 0
lock = Lock()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_count) as executor:
            executor.map(target_func, list_a)
            #time.sleep(3) # why is this here? to wait for completion?
        # tasks will be done now
        print(result)
        print(sum(list_a))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # pass # why is this here?
```

Prints:

```
500500
500500
```

Comment: the use case of this isn't summing up the list, it was purely an example to show the basics of my code, sorry if you misunderstood, great info regardless thank you

Comment: @Reseti Does any of my answer address your problem, which wasn't very clear?

Comment: actually the problem was in my target function and executor was working properly, but valuable info anyway

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, problem was inside my target function and the executor worked as it should with the max_workers value i passed